# Why does ggplot2 draw a vertical line between points?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've searched SO and the internet wide and far, but somehow can't find a reason or solution to this problem. When plotting time-series type data using `ggplot2` I always seem to have a vertical line connecting my points instead of the points being plotted singularly and simply connected via lines over time. Here's an example using `mpg`.

```
require(ggplot2)
gg <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x=year, y=cty, 
group=manufacturer, colour=manufacturer))
gg + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

Is there any way to have the vertical line connecting the points removed? And why does `ggplot2` do this? Thanks for your help in advance!

EDITED BASED ON DOWN VOTE AND QUESTIONS BELOW.

Perhaps `mpg` wasn't the best dataset to use as an example. I have multiple observations for individuals at defined time points which I want to plot by combining `geom_point()` and `geom_line()`. However, at each time point my individual observations (points) are also connected with a vertical line - which I do not know what it means and how it can be removed. Is it because I have multiple observations for the same individual at the same time-point?

Here's a dataset that helps illustrate the problem.

```
dput(x1)
structure(list(Assessment_Time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
6L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Initial", 
"First follow-up", "Second follow-up", "Third follow-up", "Fourth follow-up", 
"Fifth follow-up"), class = "factor"), id = c(454316L, 454316L, 
1184099L, 1184099L, 1184099L, 1184099L, 1184099L, 1184099L, 1184099L, 
1184099L, 124227L, 124227L, 124227L, 124227L, 124227L, 124227L, 
124227L, 124227L, 124227L, 124227L, 124227L, 124227L, 124227L, 
124227L, 1227808L, 1227808L, 1234280L, 1234280L, 1234280L, 1234280L, 
1233898L, 1233898L, 1233898L, 1233898L, 1233898L, 1233898L, 1233898L, 
1233898L, 1191086L, 1191086L, 1191086L, 1232973L, 1232973L, 1232973L, 
1232973L, 1232973L, 1232973L, 1251251L, 1251251L, 1251251L), 
    US_thickest_um = c(3400, 1500, 7600, 6000, 6600, 4500, 6100, 
    4000, 6400, 3500, 2300, 2400, 3400, 2200, 1500, 2500, 2100, 
    1500, 2500, 1700, 1700, 3800, 2800, 2800, 2300, 1300, 6000, 
    3200, 3800, 1900, 5400, 6200, 2200, 3000, 1900, 2100, 1900, 
    2500, 4600, 2800, 2100, 3400, 1900, 2400, 1700, 2100, 1300, 
    2800, 4000, 3700)), .Names = c("Assessment_Time", "id", "US_thickest_um"
), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
gg <- ggplot(x1, aes(x=Assessment_Time, y=US_thickest_um, group=factor(id)))
gg + geom_point(aes(colour=factor(id))) + geom_line(aes(colour=factor(id)))
```

Comment: Most "manufacturer" have several observations per year, and you specify that you want to connect points by "manufacturer". Please clarify your desired result.

Comment: `geom_line` connects observations by x axis. Try `geom_path` instead to see what it looks like

Comment: Because you haven't given it any other way to distinguish between observations. Run `count(mpg, manufacturer, year)` to see that you have as many as 20 observations for each combination of year and manufacturer—without any other instruction, `ggplot` will try to just plot them all in one line. How do you want to designate what should get its own line?

Comment: A time series would normally be set up differently, with each series (one per model) in a separate column.

Comment: Are you saying you want to have lines going from the value of cty for a particular model in 1999 and the value in 2008?

Comment: Based on your edited example, it sounds like your problem *is* because you have multiple observations per individual at the same time point. In that case, how do you expect them to be linked, if not be a vertical line? If you want a single point per individual per time point, you have to summarise the data to that level (e.g. with `mean()` / `median()` / etc.). Elin's answer addresses that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's not clear what you're trying to do. You refer to *time-series data* but actually use something completely different: neither `mpg` nor your updated sample data are time-series data.**

I *assume* you are asking about how to plot time-series data in `ggplot` and encode different time series in different coloured lines. Here is a simple example that should help you getting started.

First off, let's generate data for 10 time series.

```
ts <- replicate(
    10,
    ts(cumsum(1 + round(rnorm(100), 2)), start = c(1954, 7), frequency = 12),
    simplify = FALSE)
```

We convert the `ts` objects into a list of `data.frame`s.

```
lst <- lapply(setNames(ts, paste0("series_", 1:10)), function(x)
    data.frame(Y = as.matrix(x), date = as.Date(as.yearmon(time(gnp)))))
```

We now plot data by mapping `id` to the `colour` aesthetic to show the 10 different time series as 10 differently coloured line graphs.

```
library(tidyverse)    
dplyr::bind_rows(lst, .id = "id") %>%
    ggplot(aes(date, Y, colour = as.factor(id))) +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comments and reply Maurits. I typed clearly, that it is "time-series type" data, as I'm fully aware that it isn't exactly time-series. But I am unaware how else to describe data which includes observations at different time-points. No need for such hostility. I've approved all of the replies, as it seems to be an endogenous problem with my dataset, not such much an issue with ggplot2 per se. I thank you for taking the time to reply to my question.

Comment: @OFish It was not my intention to appear hostile, so I'm sorry if that was how I came across. I didn't down-vote your question, but you have to understand that a clear problem statement (preferably with a clear description of your expected output, a mock-up figure etc.) is critical for being able to help. You can see that a lot of confusion has arisen from the sample data you chose and you calling it time series data; the tone around SO can sometimes be a bit blunt, but this shouldn't be considered hostile. [...]

Comment: [...] Perhaps consider Z.Lin's comment, and if that is related to what you're trying to achieve with your data, ask a separate question with representative & minimal sample data and preferable a mock-up figure of how you'd like the data to be visualised. I wish you good luck with your work.

Answer (score 1):

It's not totally clear what your goal is here, but let's say it is to compare the mean for each manufacturer in 1999 and 2008 in a way that also shows the variation by plotting the individual points.

You could do something like this, playing around with the options until you get it the way you want.

```
means <- mpg %>% dplyr::group_by(year, manufacturer) %>% dplyr::summarize(cty = mean(cty))
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=year, y = cty)) +
    geom_jitter(aes(colour = manufacturer), width = 0.15) +
    geom_line(data = means, aes(group = manufacturer, colour = manufacturer))
```

[image: GGplot of change in cty]

Comment: Thank you for your reply Elin, I've edited my question above to make it clearer. I'm not attempting to plot the mean, and perhaps using mpg as an example dataset wasn't smart. I'll generate some dummy data to indicate what it is I would like to do and what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reconsider your plot design.

There is there is only two years. So this can't be a classic timeseries line chart.

```
library(tidyverse)
table(mpg$year)
   year     n
  <int> <int>
1  1999   117
2  2008   117
```

One of the alternatives can be this

```
gg <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x=manufacturer, fill = as.factor(cyl)))
gg + geom_bar(stat = "count") + 
  facet_wrap(~year) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: This doesn't address the issue, which is about getting distinct lines for each observation, or deciding on some means of making a summary for each grouping (the OP hasn't been clear about this). Having only 2 years doesn't change your ability to make this type of plot, or the utility of it—it's just a slopegraph.

Comment: But it isn't time series data in any meaningful sense of the way people who do data analysis define time series.